# Get an array out of a function without calling that function?

Tags: python, arrays, function, tkinter, dialog

I'm a Python beginner working on a gui, using tkinter.
I have a button which calls a function to open a csv file and read it,
then I want to get the values from this file out of the function to use it in another function. As the example code below shows, I use `return [XX , YY]` statement to get the arrays out and then I assign them (`XX, YY = Read_CSV()`). Although this works but the problem is that when I run the code, before I click the button, the open box dialog pops up. Thats because in `XX, YY = Read_CSV()` I'm calling a function which was supposed to be called only when the button is clicked.

How can I assign these arrays and get them out of the function without calling that function?

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')
Frame=LabelFrame(root, text='Frame').pack()

def Read_CSV():
    CSV_File_Name = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='/Desktop',
                                               title='Select Data File',
                                               filetypes=(('All files', '*.*'),
                                                          ('CSV file', '*.csv')))

    Data_CSV = pd.read_csv(CSV_File_Name, names=["A", "B"])

    XX = (Data_CSV['A']);
    YY = (Data_CSV['B'])

    return [XX, YY]


XX, YY = Read_CSV()
print(XX)

CSV_Read_Button = Button(Frame, text='Load Data', command=Read_CSV)
CSV_Read_Button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can't. `XX` and `YY` can't have values until the rest of the code in the function has run. Why are you doing `XX, YY = Read_CSV()` anyways though? You never use either value except to print. Just get rid of that line.

Comment: don't use `XX, YY = Read_CSV()` - you don't need it. Problem is that when button runs code then it can't get values which you send with `return` and you have to use `global` variables in `Read_CSV` to have it outside function.

Comment: BTW: see [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)  - it suggets `lower_case_names` for variables and functions and `CamelCaseNames` only for classes. It makes code more readable.

Comment: You can pass a list to `Read_CSV()` and use this list to store the return values.

Comment: Thank you every body, The answer by @furas solved the problem. This code was actually an example to reproduce my probelm, I had this problem in my code which was much more complex and messy to bring here. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: don't use `XX, YY = Read_CSV()` because it runs code at once - but you don't need it.

Second: problem is that when you press button and it runs your function then it doesn't care what you send with `return` because it doesn't know what to do with these values (you can't inform button that it has to assign it to `XX, YY`) and this is the moment when you need `global` to assign values directly to external variables.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd

# --- functions ---

def read_csv():
    global xx  # use external variable instead of local one
    global yy  # use external variable instead of local one
    
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='/Desktop',
                                          title='Select Data File',
                                          filetypes=(('All files', '*.*'),
                                                     ('CSV file', '*.csv')))


    if filename: # when user use `Cancel` then `filename will be `None`
        data = pd.read_csv(filename, names=["A", "B"])
        xx = data['A']  # it will assign to external variable
        yy = data['B']  # it will assign to external variable

    print(xx, yy)

# --- main ---

xx = None  # default value at start
yy = None  # default value at start

root = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, text='Frame')
frame.pack() # you have to do in separated line because `frame = tk.LabelFrame().pack()` gives `None` in `frame`

csv_read_button = tk.Button(frame, text='Load Data', command=read_csv)
csv_read_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

If you will add function which uses `xx`, `yy` and accidently it can be run before you load data then it is better to create `xx`,`yy` at start with some default values (ie. `None`) and check in function if `xx`,`yy` is not `None` before you try to get values from `xx`, `yy`

---

When you do

```
frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, text='Frame').pack()
```

then you assign `None` to `frame` because `pack()`/`grid()`/`place()` returns `None`. You have to do it in two lines to assign widget to variable.

```
frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, text='Frame')
frame.pack()
```

---

In `filedialog` someone can click `Cancel` and then `filename` will be `None` so you should check it before you try to use `filename` to read data.

---

See [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: This solved my problem. Thanks man. I had tried to use globals, but it seems I was wrong somewhere . 
(there is a small typo in the first line of the code you corrected, please edit it. Thanks)